# Advanced (?) Excel filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

First of all, I'd like to admit that I don't really know anything about Excel, but I have tried to look up a solution to this in Excel books and Googling.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a really long spreadsheet There are 7 columns total, but only two columns that I'm most interested in. Here's an example CSV that is much more simple than my actual dataset, but the search/sort is analogous:

```
John, Apple
Dave, Apple
Dave, Orange
Steve, Apple
Steve, Orange
Steve, Kiwi
Bob, Apple
Bob, Banana
```

I'm interested in extracting the entire rows (all of the columns) that meet the following criteria:

["Apple"] **OR** ["Apple" and "Orange"] **NOT** ["Apple" and "Orange" and *Anything Else*] **NOT** ["Apple" and *Anything that isn't Orange*]

So with the above CSV, I would get the entire rows for John and Dave, but not Steve and not Bob.

I started doing this manually, and will likely finish by the time this question has an answer, but I would like to know this for future reference.

Thanks!

Comment: So, if Bob has two rows with Apple and Banana, respectively, would you want to keep Bob's rows?

Comment: What are you doing with the "extracted" row? Is it a cut and paste? A copy and paste?

Comment: @Excellll I would not. I only want "Apple" or "Apple and Orange" as a combination.

Comment: @CharlieRB Anything really- Put it in a new sheet or cut everything that doesn't match. Doesn't necessarily need to be a clipboard interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method using three helper columns. The idea is that you can then filter for rows with value `1` in the third helper column to get the rows you want.

First helper column (column `C` in my example): Gives the count of "Apple" entries for that person.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$8,A1,$B$1:$B$8,"Apple")
```

Second helper column (column `D`): Gives the count of records for that person.

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,A1)
```

Third helper column (column `E`): Returns 1 for people matching your criteria.

```
=IF(D1=1,IF(C1>0,1,0),IF(AND(D1=2,C1=1),IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8=A1)*($B$1:$B$8="Orange"))=1,1,0),0))
```

Then just filter for the `1`s in column `E`.

[image]

You could compress these helper columns into one helper column if you needed to, but the formula would get repetitive and next-to-impossible to read.

Comment: Thank you, this looks pretty straight forward. May have to experiment with this method over the weekend!

Answer (score 0):

So bascially the number of Apple and Orange entries for a person must be equal to the number of all entries for a person. Therefore you could do this:

1. Add a new column somewhere in your table.
2. Put in the formula `=A2&"###"&B2` where `A2` is the first cell that contains the name, `B2` is the first cell that contains the fruit and `###` is a seperator that will be used neither in the name nor the fruit column. (If `###` happens to be used there, simply replace it by something else that is not to be found in those columns.)
3. Drag this formula across the whole column.
4. Add another column somewhere in your table.
5. Put in the formula `=(COUNTIF($C:$C,$A2&"###Apple") + COUNTIF($C:$C,$A2&"###Orange")) = COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)` where `C` is the column you just added in step 1, `A` is still the column with the name and `###` is the same placeholder you used in step 2.
6. Drag this formula across the whole column as well.

Result: All "invalid" rows should contain a "FALSE", all "valid" rows should contain a "TRUE".

A note of warning: Once you start deleting entries, the "FALSE" might turn into a "TRUE" - so you might want to create a hard-copy of the whole column before performing any kind of edit to the data.

HTH.

Comment: Of course this works only either under the assumption that each name has at least one Apple or under the assumption that names that only have Oranges are valid as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Next time I have to do a similar task, I'll give your method a try :)